# do dplyr mutate support runif

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I want to generate normally distributed random numbers as a column using mutate. I tried using `runif()` but it throws error on a large scale data.

```
extract_grp <- extract_grp %>%
mutate(rand = runif(sdf_nrow(extract_grp)))
glimpse(extract_grp)
```

The error that am getting is:

> Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function:
>   'RUNIF'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor
>   a permanent function registered in the database 'temp_data'.; line 1
>   pos 101   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.failFunctionLookup(SessionCatalog.scala:999)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.lookupFunction0(HiveSessionCatalog.scala:202)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.lookupFunction(HiveSessionCatalog.scala:174)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$applyOrElse$39.apply(Analyzer.scala:897)

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks jsb for the response.But I doubt if it works on dplyr and spark data frame. More over I want to generate normally distributed random numbers. I did not find any helpful content for me or I did not completely understand what you are trying to mention. please explain if I need a correction.

Comment: If your question consists of two different questions, please separate them and ask two questions instead of one nested question.

Comment: If you are using `dplyr` (and `sparklyr`?) to connect to a Spark cluster, you should mention that in your question. The problem isn't that your data is large-scale, the problem is that it is stored in Spark and dplyr doesn't know how to translate `runif` to a Spark command.

Comment: apologies for that.Thanks Gregor for taking up my concern. yes you are right its the problem with spark and dplyr. Is there any alternative for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: rand() solved my issue to an extent. I can able to generate random sequence for my hive table. But what am stuck at is to use seeding. set.seed() works for local R but is does perform on sparklyr. i.e on R Spark Hive cluster. Any alternative you can think of can be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

rand() solved my issue to an extent.

```
extract_grp <- extract_grp %>%
    mutate(rand = rand())
    glimpse(extract_grp)
```

I can able to generate random sequence for my hive table. But what am stuck at is to use seeding. set.seed() works for local R but is does perform on sparklyr.